# Best practice for chaining comparisons in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In python, it is possible to chain comparisons like so:

```
0 < 1 < 2 and 5 > 4 > 3
```

The only practice I can figure to accomplish similar in Ruby is like so:

```
0 < 1 && 1 < 2 && 5 > 4 && 4 > 3
```

Which I find to be fairly unappealing visually.

I've searched google and found some class extensions to make Ruby work like Python, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to chain comparators using just core ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1.between?(0,2)
```

`between?` works for any class which includes the Comparable module, e.g. dates, strings, arrays etc.

Comment: this fails to behave in the same manner as `0 < 1 < 2` in python as it'll return `true` for `0.between?(0,2)` when the desired reply would be `false`. This also fails to account for the other half of the problem `5 > 4 > 3` as `4.between(5,3)` returns `false`

Comment: @OneNeptune - `Comparable#between?` is what you want. This is standard behavior across many languages and part of core ruby as you requested. You can change the endpoints to work with what you have. Also,  `4.between?(3,5)` is the same as `5 > 4 > 3`.

Comment: @seph `3.between?(3,5)` should return false if it were the same as 5 > 3 > 3 , but will return true, so since the top and bottom are being delivered as variables, it'll have to be written as `3.between?(low+1,high-1)` which really doesn't seem ruby-esque at all. I'd hoped there was a more expressive answer, but it seems not. Ruby needs `y.between?(x+1,y-1)` to evaluate `x < y < z` which to me, seems out of character.

Comment: @OneNeptune - I meant in regard to the order of the arguments. Certainly the endpoints will need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

If you have basic lower and upper bounds you can use `Enumberable#include?` for range comparison like:

```
i = 10
(5 .. 20).include?(i)
```

So you know 5 is your lower-bound and 20 is your upper-bound.

`Enumberable#include?` uses `==` under the hood so it has to walk the range and compare each element, so this is poor performance for large ranges

Edit: `steenslag` answer above is way better. use that!

Comment: This does partially work, for something like `(0..2).include?(2)` I would have to remember to add the extra `.` so it's a little unintuitive. However, where things really go wrong is `(0..2).include?(0)` returns `true` when ideally considering 0 < 0 < 2 should return `false`.

Comment: Are you sure about that "has to walk the range" part? `include?` will be just a bit of busy work and a call to `cover?` here and ends up just looking at the end points of the range. `include?` or `cover?` will be slightly more expensive than manually calling `<` but not nearly as expensive as walking the entire range.

Comment: So I suppose `(0+1...2).include?(1)` would be the way to use range comparison to emulate pythons ability to evaluate `0<1<2` properly, but still seems not quite the "ruby way"

Comment: also, this fails to solve the other half of the problem `2 > 1 > 0`